# using map interface object to execute a query

Tags: java, jdbc

I have the following code with me before making any changes:

```
Connection connRemote = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://11.11.1.111:3306/test",MainUser,MainPass);
String maindbsql = null;
maindbsql = "SELECT IP_vch FROM table1 WHERE table_dt = 1"; 
// Say for example I have following values for IP_vch 11.11.11.111,22.22.22.222,33.33.33.333
Map<String,Connection> connections = new HashMap<>();
DeviceStmt = connRemote.createStatement();
DeviceRS = DeviceStmt.executeQuery(maindbsql);
 while(DeviceRS.next()){
 try{ 
  final String ip_address = DeviceRS.getString("IP_vch");
  System.out.println("Value of IP_vch Field:"+ip_address);
  connections.put(ip_address,DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ip_address + ":3306/test",RemoteUser,RemotePass));
  System.out.println("Connection to "+ip_address+" is successfull");
 }
 catch(SQLException ex1){
  System.out.println(" Inner While Loop Stack Trace Below:");
  ex1.printStackTrace();
 }
}//END Of DeviceRS.next() while loop
```

Now, I want to put a check using another SQL Query which is as follows:

```
loadchecksql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2";
```

However, if we consider the following code(slightly different from the above):

```
Connection connRemote = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://11.11.1.111:3306/test",MainUser,MainPass);
String maindbsql = null;
maindbsql = "SELECT IP_vch FROM table1 WHERE table_dt = 1"; 
loadchecksql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2";// this table2 exists only in the IP address that are in `IP_vch` field
// Say for example I have following values for IP_vch 11.11.11.111,22.22.22.222,33.33.33.333
Map<String,Connection> connections = new HashMap<>();
DeviceStmt = connRemote.createStatement();
DeviceRS = DeviceStmt.executeQuery(maindbsql);
 while(DeviceRS.next()){
 try{ 
  final String ip_address = DeviceRS.getString("IP_vch");
  System.out.println("Value of IP_vch Field:"+ip_address);
  connections.put(ip_address,DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ip_address + ":3306/test",RemoteUser,RemotePass));
  System.out.println("Connection to "+ip_address+" is successfull");
 }
 catch(SQLException ex1){
  System.out.println(" Inner While Loop Stack Trace Below:");
  ex1.printStackTrace();
 }
}//END Of DeviceRS.next() while loop
```

But `connections` is an object of Map interface and hence I am wondering how can I make the `loadchecksql` work since
I will have to do something like the following but I can't use `connections` below in place of `connRemote`:

```
LoadCheckStmt = connRemote.createStatement();
LoadCheckRS = LoadCheckStmt.executeQuery(loadchecksql);
```

I am thinking to put the above two lines just below the following line in the above code:

`connections.put(ip_address,DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + ip_address + ":3306/test",RemoteUser,RemotePass));`

Please advise

Comment: What's wrong with `connections.get(ip_address).executeQuery(...)`? (with appropriate null-checks, of course)

Comment: I haven't tried that. Let me try that. Thanks

Comment: @JimGarrison Could you tell me how am I gonna create `createStatement()` in this case since we are directly writing `executeQuery(loadchecksql);`. If I am not wrong, I just replaced the following two lines `LoadCheckStmt = connRemote.createStatement();
LoadCheckRS = LoadCheckStmt.executeQuery(loadchecksql);` with `connections.get(ip_address).executeQuery(...)` and getting error.

Comment: That's what I meant. My hint was only to get you pointed in the right direction.